# C# how to make a clock run after reading from device

Tags: c#

I know that if we want to display the pc time, we will use the below coding:

```
   System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = null;
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 1000;
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        tmr.Enabled = true;
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartTimer();
    }
```

But I do not want to display the pc time. I want to display another time (the rtc time from microcontroller for my case).

If I get the rtc time from serial port and displayed into the text box as "09:00:00". It is just static there right? How do I get it to run/increment on the text box?

I've tried the below which I modified from above coding:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer rtc = null;
    private void StartRTC()
    {
        rtc = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        rtc.Interval = 1000;
        rtc.Tick += new EventHandler(rtc_Tick);
        rtc.Enabled = true;
    }
    int i = 1;
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    void rtc_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox17.Text = dt.AddSeconds(i).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        i++;
    }
```

But the time showed on my text box always start increment on 00:00:00.

How do I let it to start increment on the time I get from my microcontroller rtc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're starting with `new DateTime()` and so you're getting and default value of a new `DateTime` class. You should initialize the value of the `DateTime` with the API call to the microprocessor.

### Example

Please note because I know nothing about the API for your microprocessor I can only write psuedo-code. In your second example, replace the following line...

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

with...

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse({some microprocessor API call for the RTC value});
```

### Edited based off of last comment

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer rtc = null; 
DateTime dt;  // NOTE I DON'T INITIALIZE THIS TO ANYTHING AT FIRST

private void StartRTC() 
{ 
    rtc = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); 
    rtc.Interval = 1000; 
    rtc.Tick += new EventHandler(rtc_Tick); 
} 

void rtc_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // NOTE I GOT RID OF i - THAT WASN'T GOING TO WORK LIKE THAT 
    // YOU JUST WANT TO ADD ONE SECOND BECAUSE THE TIMER TICKS EVERY SECOND:
    textBox17.Text = dt.AddSeconds(1).ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    dt = DateTime.Parse(textBox17.Text);
}

 // I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT YOUR METHOD HANDLER IS CALLED, THIS IS 
 // JUST FOR THE EXAMPLE
void buttonSetRtc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    // HERE IS YOUR CALL TO THE MICROCONTROLLER FOR THE INITIAL TIME:
    textBox17.Text = {some call to the microcontroller};  
    dt = DateTime.Parse(textBox17.Text);  // NOW THIS LINE WON'T FAIL
    rtc.Enabled = true;  // NOTE I MOVED THIS LINE TO KEEP IT FROM FAILING
}
```

Comment: Not really, I don't know anything about your microcontroller nor do I know what the public API is for that controller.

Comment: Like for example if I display my time on textBox.Text = "09:00:00"; How do I make it run/increment? I don't want to start at 00:00:00. I want to start the time from my RTC like for example 09:00:00.

Comment: What you have already will work to keep the timer moving and the text box updating, the issue you're having is that you're not initializing the date with the right value. Grab the value from the microprocessor API **one time** and then let the timer take it from there.

Comment: I already grab it one time. For example "09:00:00" is what I grab from the microcontroller. After grabbing it, it is a static value right? How do I make it run/increment?

Comment: @Coolguy I've updated the question to give you an example as best I can. Thanks!

Comment: U mean like this: DateTime dt = new DateTime(textBox17.Text)? textBox17 is where I put my time from the microcontroller. But it won't work also. How?

Comment: @Coolguy Sorry, copy and paste error, please see the updated answer. You need to use `DateTime.Parse`. And yes, you could use the text boxes text in place of the API call directly from there if you want.

Comment: Let me put it another way. I have a textbox which showed a value 09:00:00. How do I make it run/increment like a time?

Comment: As stated in my last comment, use `DateTime.Parse` and pass in the text value from the text box.

Comment: I got error when I put DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(textBox17.Text). What's wrong?

Comment: What's the error? Is the text box empty perhaps when trying to run `DateTime.Parse`? And no, this is the correct way, this statement works without error `DateTime.Parse("09:00:00")` and returns todays date at 9 am.

Comment: Yes. the textbox is empty at the initially. I have to click a button to get the microcontroller's time first only it will have value.

Comment: Ok, so then I guess you won't be able to initialize the date at the root class level like in your example. You will need to ***set*** the value of the class level date when you click the button. I'll update the answer with a psuedo-example.\

Comment: How do we initialize the text box value to let it not empty in the beginning?

Comment: @Coolguy It's in the example last example where I wrote the entire block. In the line above you set the text boxes text to the microcontroller's time and then in the next line you parse the text boxes text. Did you actually look at the huge added code block at the end of the answer?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the time still won't run/increment. Do we need to call StartRTC() somewhere? Your suggestion coding did not call StartRTC().

Comment: I've tried to put StartRTC() in the void buttonSetRtc_Click routine after rtc.Enabled=true line. This time, it increment one second only then stop. Then if I click the button again, it also increment one second only. Seems like it only do once StartRTC(). What's wrong?

Comment: I've edited the coding in my question. If we want to use the pc time, we will call the StartTimer() in the Form_Load() routine. But how bout for my case? Where should I call the StartRTC()?

Comment: @Coolguy - from Form_Load() - I guess I had assumed that's where you were already calling it from so I didn't try to change that.

Comment: I also found out that you need to put dt = DateTime.Parse(textBox17.Text); in void rtc_Tick() routine so that the time will keep on increment.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to initialize the Datetime dt with your microcontroller datetime.
Such as

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = dt.AddHours(9);
```

Comment: I put my microcontroller's time on a textbox. Is it doing like this DateTime dt = new DateTime(textBox17.Text)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how well this can work, but see if this is possible.

When you are able to retrieve the time from your micro controller, why not use a timer which will regularly keep reading the time from your micro controller and update your control in UI??

Comment: Is this possible in your case?

Comment: That involves too much transmission on the serial port. I'm not thinking of using this method.