# How to convert RTC value from <time.h> to datetime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

[image]

In a cortex device with battery powered clock build in (tick seconds), it generate I believe to be UTC value and use  library. That data is sent to window in C#. 
The picture shown UTC data in string and trying to adapt it to datatime for conversion to date and time to be displayed.

It generate error and not sure what went wrong, Note the value.

Comment: What do you mean by _tick seconds_ exactly? Is this value `Ticks` or `Seconds`?

Comment: This is very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11793192/2458971) . See if that solves the problem.

Comment: What date does `4294967259` represent?

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: `uint.MaxValue` ;p (but probably just -1 signed, probably indicating error)

Comment: @leppie [Hope you didn't memorize it?](https://2982-presscdn-29-70-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Shut-up-and-take-my-money.jpg) o.O

Comment: @SonerGönül: Actually not quite, but close! `0xFFFFFFDB`

Comment: (1) 1455265268 which is unix UTC. 32 bits. (2) tick second, mean the clock is ticking every second ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a TimeSpan first because tick seconds are represented by a TimeSpan, TimeSpan even has a property called TicksPerSecond:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(clickedCell.Value.ToString()));
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
```

Or of course adding it to the DateTime the tick seconds have been recorded instead of today.

EDIT: In your comment u stated the number is UNIX UTC 32 Bit, this means your DateTime you add the TimeSpan to should be the date of 01.01.1970 00:00.

Comment: Is this just an _assumption_ or you _really_ know this value should be second and result should be generated adding that value to midnight?

Comment: It is an assumption, it is up to riscy to confirm or unconfirm the use of this.

Comment: Thank I give it a try

Comment: Your DateTime should be 01.01.1970 00:00 instead of DateTime.Now when this is UNIX TIME.

Comment: Yes that work.....how to correct for GMT offset?, I get 8:42 where it should be 10:42

Comment: It need to check OS timezone and make adjustment.

Comment: With TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now); the offset between your computers TimeZone and Coordinated Universal Time will be returned as a TimeSpan you cann add this to your DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the numeric value and pass it to constructor:

```
string utc = "4294967295";
var dt = new DateTime(long.Parse(utc), DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0d47c9c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think so because this will generate `{01.01.0001 00:07:09}` as a result, so this is probably not _the_ result OP want..

Comment: Maybe your device uses POSIX time? `var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(utc)));`